# How to check the exit code from std::process::exit() in tests?

Tags: rust

In Rust tests, is there a way of checking that a function that calls [`std::process::exit()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html) really terminated the process with a specific exit code?

Contrived example:

```
fn foo(n: i32) {
    std::process::exit(n);
}

#[test]
fn exits_with_correct_exit_code() {
    // How do I assert that the following call terminates
    // the process with exit code 1?
    foo(1);
}
```

Comment: Surely you'd have to spawn a process.

Comment: I'd suggest this is a badly designed interface, though, and you should split the side-effects (`std::process::exit`) from the actual logic.

Comment: @Veedrac: I completely agree, but sometimes you are stuck with a 3rd-party function that exits on some inputs. For panics, there is at least `#[should_panic]`, but I was unable to find something that would work for `std::process::exit()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. [`std::process:exit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html) is well-named, but just in case an aspect of what it does is unclear:

> Terminates the current process with the specified exit code.
>
> This function will never return and will immediately terminate the
>   current process. The exit code is passed through to the underlying OS
>   and will be available for consumption by another process.
>
> Note that because this function never returns, and that it terminates
>   the process, no destructors on the current stack or any other thread's
>   stack will be run. If a clean shutdown is needed it is recommended to
>   only call this function at a known point where there are no more
>   destructors left to run.

When running tests, each test is run in a separate *thread*, but all tests are run within a single process. When that process is terminated, the tests go with it.

You could try to do some complicated recursive testing:

```
#[test]
#[ignore]
fn real() {
    std::process::exit(42)
}

#[test]
fn shim() {
    let status = std::process::Command::new("/proc/self/exe")
        .args(&["--ignored", "real"])
        .status()
        .expect("Unable to run program");

    assert_eq!(Some(42), status.code());
}
```

This has platform-specific code to find the current process, but it "works".

---

Honestly though, I'd say that the code is over-reaching its testing bounds. You should not be testing that `std::process::exit` does what it says it will. If you really need to assert that a function is called with an argument, that's what a [*mock object*](http://xunitpatterns.com/Mocks,%20Fakes,%20Stubs%20and%20Dummies.html) is for.

Use dependency injection to provide a closure, capture the value in the closure, and write a thin shim:

```
fn foo_logic<F>(n: i32, f: F)
    where F: FnOnce(i32)
{
    f(n);
}

fn foo(n: i32) {
    foo_logic(n, |n| std::process::exit(n));
}

#[test]
fn exits_with_correct_exit_code() {
    let mut value = None;
    foo_logic(1, |v| value = Some(v));
    assert_eq!(Some(1), value);
}
```

You may also consider extracting the logic that calculates the potential error code and testing that directly.